# Calling .focus() on input for the first time lags in Safari

Tags: javascript, performance, safari, focus

When I call `.focus()` on a text input element it takes about 10 times as much time as calling `.focus()` on the same element after that. The larger the page the longer the lag - in my case it's about a second which is very noticeable.
Clicking manually into the field has the same effect - calling `.focus()` after that is fast.

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/b80ppLhf/2/

Any ideas on how to get rid of the lag?

Comment: In fiddle, `console` says ___`0`___

Comment: @Rayon In Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Set focus in document.ready. like

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
               document.getElementById("test_input").focus()
}
```

Comment: That won't work. I set focus on a certain user event - when a tab is activated I want the field to be focused. There are many tabs with an input field on each. Setting focus on tab handle click just makes switching tabs slow because of this focus lag.

Comment: then set focus when tab is activated

Comment: That makes switching between tabs very laggy because of the .focus() lag.

Comment: try this document.querySelector('input').autofocus = true;

Comment: and make this false on your conditions

Comment: That's not working in my case. I tested more and it seems that even manual focus by clicking into a field is very slow on Safari when there's a large amount of inputs on a page.

Comment: Why dont you divide your inputs in partial view,